# Looking for a matrix "fitting" algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Given ordered sets of points $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, does an algorithm exist to find an invertible matrix $M$ so that the ordered set $C=\{ M\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\in A \}$ most closely approximates $B$? By "closely approximates", I mean that the distances between corresponding points in $B$ and $C$ are minimized.

To give some context, this question cropped up when I (who knows nothing about image processing), tried to consider an algorithm to virtually realign images. I have no idea if my approach even works in this context, but it's good to know anyways. Thanks!

Comment: Please be more clear and specific in your question. It is difficult to be certain what you are looking for. If you are seeking an algorithm to find an invertible matrix $\mathbf M$ that most closely approximates the transformation from set $A$ to set $B$ in terms of minimizing the distances between corresponding points, you may check the OPP (Orthogonal Procrustes Problem) algorithm.

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi Yes, that is what I'm looking for. I'll check it out, thanks!

Comment: Looking into it more, it seems the algorithm I'm looking for is known as a [rigid point set registration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-set_registration).